# how can i increase stack soft limit from 8mb to 100mb or more in google-colaboratory?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I need a large multi-dimensional array for my research purpose. It can not be a dynamic array and it have to be in the stack. But the problem is i can use only 8mb of google-colaboratory memory.

I have checked that its default stack soft limit is 8mb. I have tried to increase it by setrlimit, ulimit and also changing the config file in etc/security/limit.config.

But nothing has any effect on google-colaboratory. I am totally stuck in my research. So, i need help to increase the stack size. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share a self-contained notebook showing what you are trying to and the error you encounter.

Comment: after loading nvcc plugin in colab i tried to run this line in a c program, int arr[25][25][25][25][25] but it gives segmentation fault error. Later i found by !ulimit -s that its stack soft limit is only 8mb. For increasing i have used setrlimit, !ulimit -s and also changed the etc/security/limit.config file. But it has no effect on my cell.